# PHP - outputting result of 2 queries in a HTML table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to output the result from 2 queries into an HTML table using PHP?

```
<?php
    if (isset($module_id) === true) {
        $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `assignments` WHERE `module_id` = '$module_id'") or die(mysqli_error($link)); 

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0){
            echo '<p>Sorry there was no results for that specific module.</p>';
        }

        $result1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT u.first_name FROM users u 
                                        LEFT JOIN usermodule um ON um.user_id = u.user_id
                                        WHERE um.module_id = '$module_id'");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) && $row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)){
            echo
            '<tr>',
                '<td>'. $row[1] .'</td>',
                '<td>'. $row[3] .'</td>',
                '<td>'. $row1[0] .'</td>',
                '<td>',
                    '<a href="././request.php"><button class="button-link">Request</button></a>',
                '</td>',
            '</tr>';
        }
    }
?>
```

It is outputting my row1[0] variable however it is ignoring my row[1] and row[3] for my first query - any ideas?

Comment: well, you have 2 options: first dump all results into PHP arrays (separately) and then make a third loop in which you combine the two. Alternatively (better option!) is to have MySQL combine the results using just a single query by using a JOIN.

Comment: Also, what's the exact relation between the two tables? Right now you're not even sorting on anything. So it's really a random result you're getting??

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the mysqli function [mysqli_multi_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php). 
It allows multiple statements to be executed simultaneously.